# JavaScript - create a file out of json object and use it in a FormData

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, multipartform-data, form-data

I'm trying to simulate a file upload by providing file content instead of serving the real file.

So - I'm doing something like this:

```
 uploadFile(jsonContent: string, otherParams: string) {

const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('jsonContent', data, 'fileName.json');
formData.append('deal_id', dealId);

return this.http.post(this.base_url + '/files', formData);}
```

I'm not seeing the content being sent to the API.
Any advice? What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: can I see your data variable value in formData.append('jsonContent', data, 'fileName.json');?

Comment: @sorxrob it's just a js object... `{name: 'foo'}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I've found a solution for this.
In typescript you can create `new File()` and pass a blob object into it.

Now u can actually create a file in your client side and send it as part as your FormData.

here is the code:

```
    const st = JSON.stringify(json);

    const blob = new Blob([st], { type: 'application/json' });

    const file = new File([ blob ], 'FileName.json');

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file, 'FileName.json');
    formData.append('deal_id', dealId);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this in your headers

```
const headers = {
  processData: false,
  contentType: false 
}

this.http.post(this.base_url + '/files', formData, headers)
```